# How to create links as showing in highlighted round in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, view

Is there any component that android provides or any third party library who did that or I have to use view to create UI like that...This [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tes2k.png) I've captured from .psd file. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this called as customize timeline view or step view.

bellow is the best third party library which helps you.

https://github.com/qapqap/TimelineView

https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View

Comment: no thanks, Kuldeep. improve your knowledge is our motto. and please accept an answer as right.

Comment: This is better. Thanks @ChetanPatel

Comment: Thanks, @Ajay. this is my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

This is called stepview in android.

there is couple of libraries with that you can do like this.

https://github.com/baoyachi/StepView

https://github.com/ernestoyaquello/vertical-stepper-form

I personally recommended to make your own.

Comment: if this help you can you please upvote and accept the answer, Thanks